# I dont see models in django-admin which created from drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I create and save user from django-rest-framework, but it  do when i am anonymous user. Now i dont see those model in django-admin. How to add model to django-admin?

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from possible_blacklist.models import PossibleBlacklist

class PossibleBlacklistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in PossibleBlacklist._meta.get_fields()]

admin.site.register(PossibleBlacklist, PossibleBlacklistAdmin)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from possible_blacklist.models import PossibleBlacklist

class PossibleBlacklistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PossibleBlacklist
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return PossibleBlacklist.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def validate_mobile_phone(self, data):
        if data.startswith('0'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Номер должен начинаться на +380")
        return data
```

Comment: Does drf return 201?

Comment: Drf success save models and i can see their in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and when I research, I've found this good documentation which will add the model automatically to your Django admin interface.
and no need to touch your admin with every single model which are you adding.

https://medium.com/hackernoon/automatically-register-all-models-in-django-admin-django-tips-481382cf75e5